# Opening Single Modal box from multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I Need to Open a single Modal Box from Multiple buttons

The Problem is that it is working only on the first button.

For Examples :

```
 <button id="myBtn" class="myBtn" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</button>
 <button id="myBtn" class="myBtn" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</button>
```

This is The Modal Box -

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <h2>Modal Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
  <p>Some other text...</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h3 style="margin: 5px ; ">Modal Footer</h3>
</div>
```

Here's the script:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: `id` in a `html` page has to be **`unique`**

Comment: is there any solution. ?

Comment: Are you using `twitter-bootstrap`?

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: Not using teitter-bootstrap I think

Comment: Then I don't think you would be needing all these javascripts. You just add `data-target` and assign `modal`'s id to it as value..

Comment: You are using too many IDs that have the same value, when this occurs the scripts only listen to the first one. Change the event to listen to a class name rather than getElementById

Comment: Post the necessary `CSS` if you are not using `twitter-bootstrap`

Comment: data-target how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select using class name and fetch the array item with index number or a loop.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

btn[0].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};

btn[1].onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};
```

See this [Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/eVmZEr).

Comment: Thanks mate but is how can we do it when there are multiple buttons coming from database. and increasing time by time.

Comment: You can't, the IDs need to be unique. You could achieve it by using jQuery as it will listen to any instance of a class and fire the modal from there

Comment: Yes @AbnitChauhan, make a loop and do the assignment. Or you can rely on jQuery(if possible) and reassign the variable with the class selector every time the buttons come from database dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Bootstrap so that all these problem seems so easy :

**you can add as many button you want**

please look these code but need to include these boottsrap cdn in your code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id ="sample" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id ="sample" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This solution is no where in the scope of the question. You may add a 'twitter-bootstrap' tag to the question at least.